# ASP.net with HTML5 video tag and iPad

Tags: asp.net, html, video

I looked in all the question and answers and I could not resolve my problem. I am including a video player in my asp.net website using HTML5 video tag and all my files (mp4) that I retrieve from a folder work fine in IE10, FF, Chrome and Safari on my Windows 8 machine. I even tested the videos on my Android phone and everything works fine. Unfortunately, the video does not play on my iPad. The following is my code for the video tag.

```
<video id="videoPlayer"
    controls="controls"
    preload="none"
    src= '<%# Eval("VideoPath1")%>'  width="320" height="240"   />
</video>
```

I would really appreciate any help to resolve this problem.
Thank you

Comment: You have a space between the `src` attribute and the opening quote `'`, but that shouldn't do anything. Please post the final rendered HTML, not the ASP.NET source.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off including a js library to get better cross-platform performance. Have a look at [mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) or [video.js](http://www.videojs.com/).

Both are good and super easy to use - there are others.

Comment: I tried video.js but the video does not load at all. I downloaded the example and I copied an mp4 file to the root but it is not working. What am I doing wrong? Here is the source line 
    <source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4' /> Thanks

Comment: Very late answering this but the reference to video.mp4 would suggest that this file is in the root of your website.  If it isn't then the problem would be that you have not defined where that video on your site actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the video that you used is encoded correctly you can encode your video with [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/).

Change the Preset to iPhone and IPod Touch and check the Web Optimized checkbox this worked for me, the video will play on Firefox, chrome, IE, IOS and Android.